# Android layout_weight not working as intended

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to implement a layout which will be divided in 2 sublayouts. I want the left layout to be 1/4 of the screen, while the right one will be the remaining 3/4 of the screen. My goal is the following: if the user presses a button, then the left layout will get hidden and the right layout will take up the whole screen (not sure if this will work).

In order to achieve this, I tried using the following layout, which doesn't really seem to be as intended.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categoriesLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- added a dummy button to see something -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <!-- added a dummy button to see something -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As seen in the following picture, the problem is that the left `LinearLayout` is only as wide as it's content and not actually taking 1/4 of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is because you set the width of its parent layout to `wrap_content`, and if you want to have a full screen width just set it to `match_parent`, so it will be like that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz thank you Yasin :), there is a notice about your answer, when you don't provide the weight sum it takes all the assigned weights and sum them together to make the weight sum automatically, so you don't need to provide the weight sum unless you want to set it with a value different that the sum of the values of the weights under this layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
    android:weightSum="4" 
in your parent layout!

You can hide your layout1 programatically calling

```
layout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesn't do any difference

Answer (score 1):

You need `android:weightSum` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categoriesLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- added a dummy button to see something -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">

            <!-- added a dummy button to see something -->
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I get an error that `android:layout_weightSum` doesn't exist, so changing it back to `android:weightSum`, as I commented in the other answer doesn't work